# Positioning a sprite if frame rate is low

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, game-development

I use this parabolic logic when the sprite jumps. When the user clicks on the jump button, I set mVY = -300

```
int mVY = 0;   
public override void Update(GameTime theGameTime)
{
    Vector2 speed = Vector2.Zero;
    Vector2 direction = Vector2.Zero;

    if (mVY < 0)
    {
        speed.Y -= mVY;
        direction.Y = -1;
    }
    else
   {
        speed.Y += mVY;
        direction.Y = 1;
    }

    mVY += 8; 
    if (mVY > 300)  mVY = 300; // Limit maximum speed if falling

    Position += direction * speed * (float)theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

    ...
}
```

This code works ok when my game is running at 60fps, however when it's less than that the jumps are very high and slow. I thought that multiplying by theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds would fix the problem, but I must be missing something because it doesn't work properly.

Any ideas?

Comment: direction * speed * (float)theGameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds
Slower it gets  higher will be your Total Elapsed second higher will be your position.
you should refer to this article for a better explanation https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6825/time-based-movement-vs-frame-rate-based-movement

There is also a link to help you to solve your problem :)

Comment: I found this article and I think I get it this time. :) https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/29617/how-to-make-a-character-jump

Answer (score 0):

Multiply your speed by 60, since it is now in units/sec instead of units/frame.